# Eclipse IDE - Is it possible to have detached windows not always on top?

Tags: eclipse

Basically I have multiple monitors for development with Eclipse. I detach some of the windows such as the "Console" view so that I can have it fill my monitor. This is great as I can fill up my screens.

However in some cases I also want to have my browser in front while I'm coding since there's some documentation I need to look at. I can't figure out how to do this without creating another perspective...

Comment: Just a little correction: the detached window is only in front if the eclipse main window has the focus. You are able to bring the browser window in front (e.g. by using `ALT TAB`), look up what you want to know, and then bring the focus to your edit window. ==> the detached windows will then flow to the front. I think this is a feature, not a bug.

Comment: It is a feature, I'm just wondering if there's a way around it so that you can temporarily minimize the detached views.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer appears to be that you can't...

Comment: What about the solution I gave?

Answer (score 23):

You can open a new window (Window|New Window) and drag your views into this window instead of detaching them. New windows are not connected with the main one and you can control their visibility as you wish.

Comment: Eclipse Juno - this doesn't work. Maybe they noticed that it was a workaround to their bad design and decided to enforce the failed design decision? :)

Comment: @Adam Indeed, it seems it stopped working with Eclipse 4.x However you still can close the view in one window and open it in the other.

Comment: I liked this idea - but in the case of Package Explorer in a separate window - which would help my setup , the "Link with Editor" option doesn't work across windows it seems.  Any suggestions here?  Thanks

Comment: this advice is really useful! Thanks a lot for sharing! Great.

Comment: Works in Eclipse Oxygen (4.7)

Comment: Excellent answer! It works in 4.21.0

Answer (score 4):

In Eclipse Luna I had the problem that floating windows were not coming up while setting the focus on the main IDE window. It happened after I changed from 32 to 64bit using the same workspace. The windows were opened and closed correctly.

What solved the problem was reintegrating the floating windows into the main IDE window and recreated floating windows again.

Comment: such a funny workaround, I did it first time and it started working, I didn't realize how it started working. Now I take it it's an official feature ;-).

Comment: The workaround of reintegrating the window and detaching it again still works with eclipse oxygen.